# SQL - Most recent by date

Tags: database, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a consumer table which has the columns - Email, AccountState and DateCreated

AccountState can have the values 1 (active), 2 (inactive) and 3 (archived)

A specific consumer can have multiple rows consisting of the account state's above.

What I am trying to do is construct a query which returns the following

A. A list of consumer records for each consumer (using email address)

B. Only the records which aren't the most recent (so if a specific email address has 3 records, 1 for each state, it would return the 2 which aren't the most recent)

Then once I have this list I want to set all these states to 3 as they need to be archived.

So for the example data shown here

[image]

Only rows 13 - 16 would be returned.

I have tried to do this using the query below but it isn't working.

```
SELECT                  con.Email,
                        con.Id, 
                        con.DateCreated                 AS DateRegistered,
                        con.DateLastActivity,
                        con.hasiPhone,
                        con.hasAndroid,
                        con.hasSMS,
                        con.CurrencyCode                AS Currency,
                        con.AccountState


        FROM            Consumer                        con

        WHERE           con.AccountState                <> 1
        AND             DateCreated     =(  SELECT  MAX(DateCreated)
                            FROM    Consumer                        con_most_recent
                            WHERE   con_most_recent.AccountState    <> 1
                            AND     con_most_recent.Id              = con.Id)

        order by Email asc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EMail ORDER BY DateCreated DESC),
    Email, Id, DateCreated AS DateRegistered --, ... other columns
  FROM dbo.Consumer
  WHERE AccountState <> 1
)
SELECT Email, Id, DateRegistered --, ... other columns
FROM x
WHERE rn > 1
ORDER BY Email;
```

**EDIT** changing state for these rows

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EMail ORDER BY DateCreated DESC),
    Email, Id, DateCreated AS DateRegistered --, ... other columns
  FROM dbo.Consumer
  WHERE AccountState <> 1
)
UPDATE x 
SET AccountState = 3
WHERE rn > 1;
```

Comment: He wants all BUT the most recent so I think it should be rn > 1.

Comment: @BalamBalam You're right, I based it on the query the OP posted (which seemed to want to find only the most recent), not the word problem. Corrected.

Comment: wow, I dont really understand this but I will give it a go - this returned me absolutely nothing :S

Comment: The `WITH` defines a CTE (common table expression). The CTE materializes all the rows and also allows us to apply windowing functions (like `ROW_NUMBER()`) which help us to identify specific rows once we get to the outer query (such as eliminating the most recent row for each consumer). It wasn't clear from your query or word problem if you wanted to eliminate all rows where `AccountState <> 1` or just the oldest?

Comment: Hi Aaron, I would to return in the query every consumer record for a specific email address (which isn't the most recent entry). Hope that makes sense

Comment: No, it would make more sense if you show sample data and desired results. Word problems were fun in grade school but not when trying to reverse engineer business problems.

Comment: Ok lets take the sample data as this (http://imgur.com/72azm) the rows that would be returned would be 3, 6, 9 - 12, 14 - 16, 18, 20 - 22. Does that make it easier?

Comment: Ignore the above comment. Sample data of this (http://imgur.com/r0XyC) would return the following highlighted rows (http://imgur.com/Gilgc) hope that helps and makes things easier

Comment: Aaron ... it returns me absolutely nothing.

Comment: I changed the partitioning from Id to Email, could you try again please?

Comment: I guess that I would have to perform some kind of cursor to update the account state's to 3 for these records

Comment: No, you don't need a cursor. You can also use the CTE to perform other operations. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @AaronBertrand ... aww wow I never knew about this kind of SQL statements, many thanks for your help its much appreciated.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - when running the updated answer I get the following "Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 17
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'."

Comment: @AaronBertrand - it's fine you missed AccountState out of the select within 'X' all sorted now, many thanks

Comment: Line 17? What line is line 17? It is very hard to troubleshoot code I can't see.

Comment: Uh, that is why I put `--, ... other columns` - I didn't want to clutter the answer with all your column names but expected you to fill them in.